# How local is each country's version of Google?

Tags: seo, google, internationalization, international

I know that you can drill down on the particular language or country version of google from "Search tools," but even discounting for that, and removing personalisation etc, I'm still seeing different results for the same search between google.com and google.co.uk, for example. All things being equal, are these really supposed to be showing exactly the same results?

Answer (score 1):

> are these really supposed to be showing exactly the same results?

No. There might be a lot of overlap, but `google.com` targets its results to a US audience and `google.co.uk` delivers results that are supposed to be more relevant to a UK audience.

The results returned aren't necessarily "local" to each region, however, they are deemed to be relevant to someone in that region when searching for whatever phrase they have searched for.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea at all as to how these results are collected different from e.g. google.co.uk vs. going to search tools and selecting "Country:UK" on that domain?

Comment: Searching on google.co.uk returns results that are _relevant_ to someone in the UK. The sites returned could be located anywhere in the world (the default). However, selecting Search Tools > Country:UK narrows this search and returns sites that are themselves located in the UK.

Comment: "located in the UK" - or to put it another way, "sites that are _geotargetted_ to the UK" (in reference to [your other question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61078/hreflang-or-geotargeting)).