# In SEO & SEM terms, use of a international domain vs a local domain

Tags: seo, domains, search-engines, multiple-domains, local-seo

In terms of SEO & SEM if I have a .com and a .co.uk. Would it be better to use the .com and park the .co.uk, If I am selling the product locally (in the uk) and later moving out into the international market?

Will I struggle more to compete locally with regards to local searches and Google Adwords, if I make the .com as the primary domain?

Does the parking of the .co.uk or the .com effect the relevance of a web domains search locally and internationally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both. But not with the same content or not without a 301 redirect of some sort. If you are competing locally at first, then redirect the .com to the .co.uk site and do all the local SEO stuff on the .co.uk site to compete well. As the company grows, then the .co.uk site can be more company related and the .com can be product related. In fact, you can do that now if you want. You do not have to park either site.

Now if you decide that the .co.uk site should be a company site, then you can cover your products but refer your users to full details on the .com site and vice versa.

I think it all depends upon how much content you can create for both the company and the product. If you can create enough content that each site can stand and compete on it's own, then okay. Otherwise, you may be better off creating the .co.uk site in full and redirecting the .com site to the .co.uk site. If you redirect the entire site with a 301 redirect, you should be okay.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, this make perfect sense now.

Comment: Anytime. I wrote an answer I wanted to link to where I discuss how ccTLDs are treated by Google and the effect on SEO, but I cannot find it yet and it really does not apply. The up-shot was that people thought that sites like .co.uk would only perform well in the UK, but that is not true and I explained how Google populates the various data centers based upon general performance (not site performance). I thought it could be interesting.

Comment: I am always looking around for anything that might help boost a new website. Thanks again

Comment: Found it! Just FYI. You might find it interesting. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61456/is-it-worth-always-geotargeting-your-site/61460#61460